# NoReferencedTableError while using transaction to insert data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am building a simple poll web app and i need to insert polls in the database, at the moment the polls are represented in a JSON structure this way:

```
[
    {
        "title":"Do you like dogs?",
        "type":"select",
        "options":[
            "Yes",
            "No"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title":"What type of dogs do you like?",
        "type":"choices",
        "options":[
            "All",
            "None",
            "Labrador"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title":"Why do you like dogs?",
        "type":"text"
    },
    {
        "title":"How much do you like dogs?",
        "type":"range"
    }
]
```

This is the code i am using at the moment:

```
@polls.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def pollcreate_post():
    data = request.form
    r, l, valid = [], None, {'select', 'text', 'range', 'checkbox', 'choices', 'range', 'date'}
    options = { 'select', 'checkbox', 'choices'}
    for a, b in data.items():
        if a in valid:
            l = a
            r.append({'title':b, 'type':a})
        elif a.startswith('option') and l in options:
            r[-1]['options'] = [*r[-1].get('options', []), b]
    try:
        pollname = 'Polls Test Name'
        newpoll = Poll(pollname=pollname, polldate=datetime.now())
        newpoll.questions = []
        db.session.add(newpoll)
        for question in r:
            questiontype = question['type']
            questiontitle = question['title']
            questiontypeid = QuestionType.query.filter_by(name=questiontype).first()
            categoryid = Category.query.filter_by(name='Animals').first()
            newquestion = Question(questiontypeid=questiontypeid.questiontypeid, categoryid=categoryid.categoryid, title = questiontitle, required=False)
            newquestion.answers = []
            if questiontype in {'select', 'checkbox', 'choices'}:
                for qoption in question['options']:
                    newanswer = Answer(questionid=newquestion.questionid,name=qoption)
                    newquestion.answers.append(newanswer)
            newpoll.questions.append(newquestion)
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        raise
    return render_template('poll-create.html')
```

I don't know why but when receiving the data and inserting the answers it raises this exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'PollQuestions.questionid' could not find table 'questions' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'questionid'
```

Here you can find my models:

```
pollquestions = Table('PollQuestions', Base.metadata,
Column('pollid', Integer, ForeignKey('polls.pollid'), primary_key=True),
Column('questionid', Integer, ForeignKey('questions.questionid'), primary_key=True))

class Poll(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'polls'
    
    pollid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    pollname = Column(String(255))
    polldate = Column(Date)
    questions = relationship("Question", secondary=pollquestions)

class Question(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'

    questionid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    questiontypeid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('QuestionTypes.questiontypeid'))
    categoryid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Categories.categoryid'))
    title = Column(String(255))
    required = Column(Boolean)
    polls = relationship("Poll", secondary=pollquestions)
    answers = relationship("Answer")
    polls = relationship("Poll")

class Answer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'answers'

    answerid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    questionid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Questions.questionid'))
    name = Column(String(255))
```

Comment: If you are certain the table exists, could it be in a different schema of the database? Or could the case sensitivity play a role?

Comment: i dont know i didnt define anything particular on the db schema, maybe case sensitivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Question` class apparently has a `questionid` attribute that is automatically generated by the database. Immediately after you create a new `Question` object its `questionid` attribute is `None`. Adding the object to the session does not change that value because everything so far has happened on the SQLAlchemy side.

If you need the actual value of `questionid` you must do a `db.session.flush()` to send the INSERT statement to the database and update the ORM object. Then `newquestion.questionid` will no longer be `None` and you can create the `Answer` object as before.

Alternatively, you can set up a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html) in the `Answers` class so you can define the related `Question` in terms of its *object* rather than its `questionid` value.

Comment: I have tried doing what you have suggested now, (i am still new to this) now i have a new problem could you help me out with that? i have updated the question

Comment: Does a table named `Polls` actually exist in the database?

Comment: Yes the table Polls exists

Comment: Can SQLAlchemy "see" it? Add `insp = db.inspect(db.engine)` to your route and have it echo the value of `str(insp.has_table("Polls"))`. Does it show `True`?

Comment: Yes it returns me True

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql at the moment

Comment: Try specifying the `__tablename__` in your models as all lowercase, e.g. `__tablename__ = "questions"`, and then always refer to the tables as lowercase, e.g., `questions.questionid` while referring to the classes as mixed-case, e.g., `Question`

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work i have updated the code and the error

Comment: [This code](https://pastebin.com/eNNy59fJ) works for me.